# Scala Specs2: how to get current test name?

Tags: scala, specs2

I'm working with Scala project, using Specs2 for testing.
How could I know the test name i'm currently within it (form the test context)?

This is the code structure of my tests:

```
    class TestsE2E{
       trait Context extends E2EScope {
         ...
       }

       "Test" should {
         "do stuff" in new Context {
            ...
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use the test name to log it, you can create a custom `ExamplesFactory` to intercept the name:

```
import org.specs2.mutable.{FragmentsBuilder, ExamplesFactory}

trait TestNameLogger extends ExamplesFactory { this: FragmentsBuilder =>
   override implicit def exampleFactory: ExampleFactory = new TestNameLoggerMutableExampleFactory

   class TestNameLoggerMutableExampleFactory extends MutableExampleFactory {
     override def newExample(e: Example): Example = {
       println(e.desc.raw)
       super.newExample(e)
     }
   }
}
```

This solution is a bit involved and the API for doing this will change with the upcoming [specs2 3.0](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide-specs2-three/org.specs2.guide.FragmentsApi.html#the-fragments-api). Another alternative is to create your own [`Notifier`](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Runners.html#Notifier).

Comment: Eric, can you please elaborate how to do it in my specific code structure (i have edited the question)?

Comment: It depends. Does your E2EScope trait provide access to some variables? And what do you want to do with the test name?

Comment: Currently it calls for configuration methods the responsible for testing environment to launch. I want to use the test name for some logging purposes.